# C# LinQ Conditional OrderBy

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

so this is my query

```
 var results = tcs.Skip(searchModel.PageSize * (searchModel.Page - 1))
                .Take(searchModel.PageSize)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    trackId = x.TrackId,
                    trackName = x.TrackName,
                    category = _weCategoryService.FindAll().Where(y => y.WorkExperience_Track.TrackId == x.TrackId)
                        .Select(y => new {
                            categoryId = y.CategoryId,
                            categoryName = y.CategoryName,
                            skill = _skillsService.FindAll().Where(z => z.CategoryId == y.CategoryId)
                                .Select(z => new {
                                    skillId = z.SkillId,
                                    skillName = z.SkillName
                                }).OrderBy(z => z.skillName).ToList()
                        }).OrderBy(y => y.categoryName).ToList()
                }).OrderBy(x => x.trackName).ToList();
```

Then i have a model which has a boolean value for `SortTrack`, `SortCategory` and `SortSkills`.
I want to OrderBy Ascending if the value of the boolean is true and Descending if false.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Don't be inline. It's hard to read.

Comment: @TânNguyễn i dont know how to inline a linq query and i also thats how i do my code so its easier for me to read it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In lambda it can be done like this:

```
var results = tcs.Skip(searchModel.PageSize * (searchModel.Page - 1))
                    .Take(searchModel.PageSize)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        trackId = x.TrackId,
                        trackName = x.TrackName,
                        category = _weCategoryService.FindAll().Where(y => y.WorkExperience_Track.TrackId == x.TrackId)
                            .Select(y => new {
                                categoryId = y.CategoryId,
                                categoryName = y.CategoryName,
                                skill = _skillsService.FindAll().Where(z => z.CategoryId == y.CategoryId)
                                    .Select(z => new {
                                        skillId = z.SkillId,
                                        skillName = z.SkillName
                                    }).OrderBy(z => SortSkills ? z.skillName : "").OrderByDescending(z => !SortSkills ? z.skillName : "").ToList()
                            }).OrderBy(y => SortCategory ? y.categoryName : "").OrderByDescending(y => !SortCategory ? y.categoryName : "").ToList()
                    }).OrderBy(x => SortTrack ? x.trackName : "").OrderByDescending(x => !SortTrack ? x.trackName : "").ToList();
```

Else you need to use expressions like this:

```
var x = widgets.Where(w => w.Name.Contains("xyz"));
if (flag) {
  x = x.OrderBy(w => w.property);
} else {
  x = x.OrderByDescending(w => w.property);
}
```

Comment: Does OrderBy("") still iterate over the whole list?

Comment: @RabidPenguin I think no. This will be equilent to OrderBy(x => "") so here we are not implementing this orderby on any column it will not iterate.

Answer (score 2):

Linq statements are composable so you can add the appropriate orderby to the query before calling tolist.

```
var query = list.Where(...)
if (condition)
    query = query.OrderBy(...)
else
    query = query.OrderByDescending(...)

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: can you edit my code using that?? because i tried like that but got a problem in the 3rd object which is it cannot find the id

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few other options more in the LINQ spirit.  EF won't be able to translate them to SQL, so you'll need to run these in-memory (post-AsEnumerable/ToArray/ToList) but it looks like it won't be a problem.

Take this as a simple example:

```
var numbers = new int[] { 5, 1, 2, 3, 44 };
```

**Option 1**

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderByAdaptive<T, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<T> enumr, 
        Func<T, TKey> selector, 
        bool ascending
    )
    {
        return ascending
            ? enumr.OrderBy(selector)
            : enumr.OrderByDescending(selector);
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderByAdaptive<T, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<T> enumr, 
        Func<T, TKey> selector, 
        IComparer<TKey> comparer, 
        bool ascending
    )
    {
        return ascending
            ? enumr.OrderBy(selector, comparer)
            : enumr.OrderByDescending(selector, comparer);
    }
}
```

*Usage*

```
var asc = true; // or false
var sorted = numbers.OrderByAdaptive(x => x, asc);
```

**Option 2**

```
public class LambdaComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T, T, int> _cmp;

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, int> cmp)
    {
        _cmp = cmp;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return _cmp(x, y);
    }
}
```

*Usage*

```
var ascComparer = new LambdaComparer<int>((x, y) => { 
    if (x > y) return 1; 
    else if (x < y) return -1; 
    else return 0; 
});

var descComparer = new LambdaComparer<int>((x, y) => { 
    if (x > y) return -1; // Note the sign change
    else if (x < y) return 1; // Note the sign change
    else return 0; 
});

var asc = true; // or false

var sorted = numbers.OrderBy(x => x, asc ? ascComparer : descComparer);
```

**Option 3**

```
public class ReverseComparer<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private IComparer<T> _nonReversed;

    public ReverseComparer()
    {
        _nonReversed = Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public ReverseComparer(IComparer<T> nonReversed)
    {
        _nonReversed = nonReversed;
    }

    public int Compare(T obj1, T obj2)
    {
        return -1 * _nonReversed.Compare(obj1, obj2);
    }
}
```

*Usage*

```
var ascComparer = Comparer<int>.Default;
var descComparer = new ReverseComparer<int>(); // or new ReverseComparer<int>(ascComparer);

var asc = true; // or false

var sorted = numbers.OrderBy(x => x, asc ? ascComparer : descComparer);
```

Production-wise, I would probably create a `SortDirection` enum with `Ascending` and `Descending` values rather than a bool named `asc`, but I'm silly like that.